# How can I ADD an external webcam to Android Phone (Samsung Galaxy)

Tags: android, webcam

I want to ADD an external webcam to an Android phone. Ideally a plain old USB webcam, but I am open to anything that works.

I do NOT want to use my Android phone as a webcam. In no way does a PC/laptop factor into the equation here. Just adding another camera to an android phone.

Thanks so much,
Josh